# doing a loop without "predefining" cells (ie just "B" instead of "b5")

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Here's my problem: I'm trying to run a loop over a specific set of data, where the amount changes with each update.   If the score is >0, then it will cut/paste the specific row in columns A,B&C in the next available free row in the sheet data.
 This is what I have up till now:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim score As Integer, sStart As Integer, sTeller As Integer, lcount As Integer, result As String

    sStart = Sheets("Packed").Range("F1").Value
    sTeller = Sheets("Packed").Range("E1").Value
    lcount = sStart
    score = Range("B& lcount").Value

    Do While lcount < sTeller
        Sheets("Packed").Select
        If score > 0 Then _ 
            Range("A&lcount:C&lcount").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("data").Select
        Range("A5").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        lcount = lcount + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

What I would like is that VBA adds the "lcount" to the rowlabel and then loops it for each row in B where there is data.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `Range("B" & lcount)`.  If `lcount` = 5 that would evaluate to `Range("B5")`

Comment: ... or `Cells(lcount, "B")` or `Cells(lcount, 2)`. See [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Range.Cells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including too many 'pieces' when concatenating the quoted string in this code:

```
If score > 0 Then _ 
    Range("A&lcount:C&lcount").Select
```

Here are some suggestions:

```
If score > 0 Then _ 
    Range("A" & lcount & ":C" & lcount).Select

If score > 0 Then _ 
    Cells(lcount, "A").Resize(1, 3).Select
```

You may also want to review the methods detailed in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 0):

Loop not required in your case, see your updated code below

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim score&, sStart&, sTeller&, lcount&
    lcount = Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets("Packed")
        sStart = .Range("F1").Value
        sTeller = .Range("E1").Value
        score = .Range("B" & sStart).Value
    End With
    If score > 0 Then
        Sheets("Packed").Range("A" & sStart & ":C" & sTeller - 1).Cut
        Sheets("data").Activate: Range("A" & lcount).Insert xlDown
    End If
End Sub
```